# why does integration by parts give a different answer

Tags: integration

so i know the answer for $\int{\frac{x \, dx}{(x+b)^{2}}} \quad \textrm{is} \quad \frac{b}{x+b} + ln|x+b| $

But i tried integration by parts and obtained the following, 
Setting $ u= x, \, du=dx, \, dv = \frac{dx}{(x+b)^{2}}, \, v=\frac{-1}{x+b} $

$ \int{\frac{x \, dx}{(x+b)^{2}}}= \frac{-x}{x+b} + ln|x+b|$

Does it have anything to do with any possible singularities in the integrand?

Answer (score 14):

Both results are true, they just differ by a constant :

$$
\frac{-x}{x+b} + \ln|x+b|=\frac{-x-b+b}{x+b}+\ln|x+b|=\color{red}{-1}+\frac{b}{x+b}+\ln|x+b|.
$$

Comment: workaholic, how are you progressing with your linear algebra?

Comment: This is not really a *hint*.

Comment: And *if it was* a hint then it shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: @FengyangWang I initially just wrote the first sentence, but after posting it I immediately edited my answer to include those equalities, forgetting to remove the *hint*.

Comment: Dear @abel $\!,$ Sorry, I didn't saw the message you sent me last time via e-mail, I'm sorry for that, I'll respond to it later. :-) *(I was very busy these last days)*